# Codeigniter set_value not working on other tabs

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently working on a form that has many tabs. When there is an error I want to repopulate the form. It is working for the first tab in my form however for other tabs, it wont repopulate. Any ideas on what is wrong?

The tabNum variable is to make it so that when the user submits the form, the page redirects back to the correct tab.

### Controller

```
function addResearchMicroFundView()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        //Get information from session  
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

        $user = $this->user_model->getUsernameNameLevel($session_data['user_id']);

        foreach ($user as $row)
        {

        }

        $data['user_id'] = $session_data['user_id'];
        $data['username'] = $row->username;
        $data['name'] = $row->name;
        $data['level'] = $row->level;
        $data['page'] = "addResearchMicroFund";

        if (!$this->session->flashdata('tabNum'))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('tabNum', 1);
        }
        $this->load->view('addResearchMicroFund_view', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        //If no session, redirect to login page
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
}

function addSubmitApplicantDetails()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('applicant_name', 'Name of Applicant', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('academic_position', 'Academic Position', 'required|in_list[A,B1,B2,C,D,E]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('applicant_faculty', 'Faculty / Centre / Unit', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('tabNum', $this->input->post('tabNum'));
        $this->addResearchMicroFundView();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

function addSubmitResearchDetails()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('research_title', 'Research Title', 'required|is_natural');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_summary', 'Project Summary', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_necessity', 'Necessity of the item for the project', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('expected_outcome', 'Expected Outcome', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('tabNum', $this->input->post('tabNum'));
        $this->addResearchMicroFundView();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

### View

```
    <section class="content-header">
        <?php if(validation_errors()):?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><Strong><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></Strong></div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('tabNum') == 1){echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">Applicant Details</a></li>
                <li <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('tabNum') == 2){echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">Research Details</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab">Recommendation</a></li> -->
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('tabNum') == 1) echo "class='tab-pane active'"; else echo "class='tab-pane'"; ?> id="tab_1">
                    <div class="box box-primary">
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Applicant Details</h3>
                        </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                        <?php
                            $attributes = array('role' => 'form', 'data-toggle' => 'validator','id' =>'validateForm');
                            echo form_open('researchMicroFund/addSubmitApplicantDetails',$attributes)?>
                        <!-- form start -->
                        <form role="form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="tabNum" value="1"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id?>"/>
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>Name of Applicant</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="applicant_name" name="applicant_name" value="<?=!form_error('applicant_name')?set_value('applicant_name'):''?>" placeholder="Name of Applicant" required>
                                    <div class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>Academic Position</label>
                                    <p class="help-block">(A, B1, B2, C, D or E)</p>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="academic_position" name="academic_position" value="<?=!form_error('academic_position')?set_value('academic_position'):''?>" placeholder="Academic Position" required>
                                    <div class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>Faculty / Centre / Unit</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="applicant_faculty" name="applicant_faculty" value="<?=!form_error('applicant_faculty')?set_value('applicant_faculty'):''?>" placeholder="Faculty / Centre / Unit" required>
                                    <div class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>Type of Service</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="service_type" name="service_type" required onchange="disableContractExpiryDate()">
                                        <option <?php echo set_select('service_type', 'Tenure', TRUE); ?> value="Tenure">Tenure</option>
                                        <option <?php echo set_select('service_type', 'Contract'); ?> value="Contract">Contract</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>Contract Expiry Date</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="expiry_date" name="expiry_date" value="<?=!form_error('expiry_date')?set_value('expiry_date'):''?>" placeholder="Contract Expiry Datet" required>
                                    <div class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                            <div class="box-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div><!-- /.box -->
                </div>
                <div <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('tabNum') == 2) echo "class='tab-pane active'"; else echo "class='tab-pane'"; ?> id="tab_2">
                    <div class="box box-primary">
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Research Details</h3>
                        </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                        <?php
                            $attributes = array('role' => 'form', 'data-toggle' => 'validator','id' =>'validateForm');
                            echo form_open('researchMicroFund/addSubmitResearchDetails',$attributes)?>
                        <!-- form start -->
                        <form role="form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="tabNum" value="2"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id?>"/>
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>Title of Proposed Research</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="research_title" name="research_title" value="<?=!form_error('research_title')?set_value('research_title'):''?>" placeholder="Title of Proposed Research" required></textarea>
                                    <div class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>Summary of Project</label>
                                    <p class="help-block">(not more than 200 words)</p>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="project_summary" name="project_summary" value="<?=!form_error('project_summary')?set_value('project_summary'):''?>" placeholder="Summary of Project" required></textarea>
                                    <div class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>The necessity of the item for the project</label>
                                    <p class="help-block">(not more than 200 words)</p>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="item_necessity" name="item_necessity" value="<?=!form_error('item_necessity')?set_value('item_necessity'):''?>" placeholder="The necessity of the item for the project" required></textarea>
                                    <div class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>Expected Outcome</label>
                                    <p class="help-block">(not more than 200 words)</p>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="expected_outcome" name="expected_outcome" value="<?=!form_error('expected_outcome')?set_value('expected_outcome'):''?>" placeholder="Expected Outcome" required></textarea>
                                    <div class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                            <div class="box-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div><!-- /.box -->
                </div>
```

How my form looks.
[image]

Comment: Did you set each tab with difference url?

Comment: It's in the same url

Comment: Can you try with this code at research_title input? `<?=!form_error('research_title')?set_value('research_title'):form_error('research_title')?>`

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because it's working fine on the first tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. The problem does not lies with the tabs.

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="research_title" name="research_title" value="<?=!form_error('research_title')?set_value('research_title'):''?>" placeholder="Title of Proposed Research" required></textarea>
```

Text area does not have values. Stupid mistake. So the solution should be:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="research_title" name="research_title" placeholder="Title of Proposed Research" required><?=!form_error('research_title')?set_value('research_title'):''?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear, you need to pass the error at new line. E.g:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="academic_position" name="academic_position" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('academic_position') ?>" placeholder="Academic Position" required>
<?= form_error('academic_position') ?>
```

Hopefully it will help you.